# Does accessing a related object through self hit the database in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

In Django, if I have a ForeignKey or a ManyToMany field in a model, is the database hit every time I try to access them through self?

How many time is the database hit in this example?

```
# loop done 10 times
for x in looping_array:
    print(self.foreign_key_object)
    print(self.many_to_many_field.first())
```

**EDIT**: added the many_to_many_field line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will hit DB only once. Second and later calls will use cached data. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#one-to-many-relationships):

> Forward access to one-to-many relationships is cached the first time
>   the related object is accessed. Subsequent accesses to the foreign key
>   on the same object instance are cached. Example:

```
>>> e = Entry.objects.get(id=2)
>>> print(e.blog)  # Hits the database to retrieve the associated Blog.
>>> print(e.blog)  # Doesn't hit the database; uses cached version.
```

As for `manytomany` sinse `self.many_to_many_field.first()` is a queryset this will not be cached and will hit db on each iteration.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you. I couldn't find info for the ManyToMany case though... I added a line to my example so that you can see what I am referring to.

Comment: @RyanPergent manytomany fields on the other side will not be cahed this way.